# Why would anyone define a static method in an interface in java 1.8?

Tags: java, interface, java-8, static-methods

Why would any one define a static method in an interface in JAVA 1.8?

I need to know the different examples/usecases/requirements where static method would come handy.

How can a static method in an interface would be beneficial for a developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I found nice explanation why we have static methods in interfaces: 
http://www.baeldung.com/java-static-default-methods

> The idea behind static interface methods is to provide a simple
>   mechanism that allows us to increase the degree of cohesion of a
>   design by putting together related methods in one single place without
>   having to create an object.
>
> Pretty much the same can be done with abstract classes. The main
>   difference lies in the fact that abstract classes can have
>   constructors, state, and behavior.
>
> Furthermore, static methods in interfaces make possible to group
>   related utility methods, without having to create artificial utility
>   classes that are simply placeholders for static methods.

So yes, the one of the examples is that instead of creating utility classes for some behavior, calculation related to your interface, you can choose to define related static methods directly in the interface. So you group functionality on the right place. You avoid additional classes

```
public interface Vehicle {

  static int getHorsePower(int rpm, int torque) {
        return (rpm * torque) / 5252;
    }
}   

Vehicle.getHorsePower(2500, 480));



public interface Cube {

      static double volume(double a){
          return a * a * a;
      }

      static double surface(double a){
         return 6*a*a;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There are many use cases for static methods in interfaces. The **most common** by far, though, is factory methods that have made it easy to create instances of their respective interfaces.

Consider these examples:

```
Comparator.comparing
List.of
Set.of
Stream.of, Stream.generate
```

Without these factory methods in interfaces, there would be too many constructor calls in disparate implementation classes.

Some of these examples were only added with version 9 of Java, but the feature opened many possibilities.

These static methods are also used for different purposes. It's now possible to have a method like `Collections.sort` implemented in the right place, `Collection.sort`, thus avoiding unnecessary extra classes.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the reference. I use this method so often but never noted that these are the static methods too and they do help me in making calls simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Most commonly, factory and utility classes.

In addition to the factory examples in the other answer, consider the `Collections` class - this has been in the JDK for over a decade, but would never have been needed if the static methods could just have been defined on the `Collection` interface from day 1.

Comment: Yeah, true that...
Any reason can you think of that java language developers created collections class with the static methods but doesn't implemented these static methods in the collection interface? Is it because now the classes can extend the functionality of these static methods. But this is not possible through implementing the Collection interface as static methods can't be inherited from an interface. Is that so?

Comment: If the methods were introduced now, they'd almost certainly be part of the collection interface - but when the Collections class was introduced, static methods on interfaces weren't allowed. (And it almost certainly won't be changed now for backwards compatibility reasons.)

Comment: Alright, that clarifies my doubt. Thanks